# How to record voice in the iTranslate Voice application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How in this  [application](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id522626820?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)  has writing voice and voice to text conversion.
I heard about a program such as ispeech. They used this app or not, or is there some sort of built-in ability to do the conversion from voice to text?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Some_other_guy yes, first part question its "how in apps has writting voice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm used [this](https://github.com/bluefragma/SmartRecorder) lib, just ported from objective C to xamarin